# AnyLogic - make many edit boxes visible depending on variable

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Here is a simplified example of my problem:
[image]

I want to make the edit box 1 or 2 visible, depending on whether a checkbox of box 1 or box 2 is checked. The variables "variableCheckbox1" and "variableCheckbox2" are connected to the respective ceckboxes.

I have written a function as shown in the picture. The function is called from the EditBox 1 ("Enabled"). This is a possible solution for ONE box each.

Does anyone have an idea if there is a more elegant way to do this for a very high number of checkboxes / edit boxes?
A possible solution would be to write a function with a switch case for each variable in my model, called from each box. A very inelegant solution would be to make a single function for each box, but I don't consider that a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this for a large number, turn the entire setup into its own agent type: Checkbox and editbox. Instantiate as needed, you can add a parameter to specify what this is about exactly...

This would be the most generic and powerful approach...

Comment: very good idea, Benjamin. For my model it is an overkill, but definitely the best idea for a very large number and indeed a very powerful approach

Answer (score 2):

if this works for you, you can use replications for checkboxes and editboxes and associate them together through the index... and then just add the code in the visible field of the edit box... Of course you will have to determine their positions programatically

[image]